# Pass user name while running test using maven command

Tags: java, maven, selenium, maven-plugin

We would like to create test report specific to user who fired the request in the server. If we change pom this way

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/${user.name}</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

This produces the user name of the server, not the individual who fired the test. I have seen one possible solution like `mvn surefire-report:report -DoutputDirectory=newpath`. But wondering, how can we pass the user name through command prompt.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in your pom file:

```
<pom>
    ...
    <properties>
        <some.propertyName></some.propertyName>
    </properties>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/${some.propertyName}</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</pom>
```

Then you use it like this:

```
mvn surefire-report:report -Dsome.propertyName=DonaldDuck
```

Comment: The above answer work perfectly and creates corresponding director with my user name. After testing it further, I came with another complexity.

Comment: The above answer work perfectly and creates corresponding director with my user name. After testing it further, I came with another complexity. If somebody would like run any test who has not got any maven installation, we would like to get a HTTP request from that user and the corresponding maven command would be fired in the server. To get this done, I think, we need to a capability to run the test using maven command where we would not depend on property defined in POM, but rather use system properties. The request could be like mvn -Dtest=*.java -DoutputDirectory=<user.name>. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just set the default property to whatever you want, `<some.propertyName>${user.name}</some.propertyName>`. Then with the HTTP request just call the maven command without the `-Dsome.propertyName`.